# Haskell Recursive Type

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I am attempting to create a function in Haskell returning the `Resp` type illustrated below in a strange mix between BNF and Haskell types.

```
elem ::= String | (String, String, Resp)
Resp ::= [elem]
```

My question is (a) how to define this type in Haskell, and (b) if there is a way of doing so without being forced to use custom constructors, e.g., `Node`, rather using only tuples and arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part 1:

```
data Elem = El String | Node String String Resp
type Resp = [Elem]
```

Part 2: Well... kinda. The unsatisfying answer is: You shouldn't want to because doing so is less type safe. The more direct answer is `Elem` needs it's own constructor but `Resp` is easily defined as a type synonym as above. However, I would recommend

```
newtype Resp = Resp { getElems :: [Elem] }
```

so that you can't mix up some random list of `Elem`s with a `Resp`. This also gives you the function `getElems` so you don't have to do as much pattern matching on a single constructor. The `newtype` basically let's Haskell know that it should get rid of the overhead of the constructor during runtime so there's no extra indirection which is nice.

Comment: Thank you! At least I was on the right track with the type definitions; the variety of keywords (`data`, `type`, `newtype`) has been confusing for me. My question now is: How do I prevent errors such as "couldn't match Elem with String" for the `data` defined type?

Comment: It should be `data Elem = El String | Node String String Resp`

Comment: @Ankur What is `El`? And what constructor do I use to make a given string pattern-match that?

Comment: `El` is the data constructor and you will use it for pattern matching : `myfun (El str) = ...` You can use any name instead of `El`

Comment: @Ankur Right you are, that's what happens when I answer SO questions at 2am

Comment: "You shouldn't want to because doing so is less type safe", what does that mean? With strong type checking, everything that is allowed will be type safe; there is no such thing as more or less type safe.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is meant in the informal sense of "makes less use of the type system to prevent errors" not in the sense of "the program will not get stuck". It's ambiguous terminology that I try and avoid nowadays though.

Answer (score 14):

You said that "the variety of keywords (data, type, newtype) has been confusing for me". Here's a quick primer on the data construction keywords in Haskell.

### Data

The canonical way to create a new type is with the `data` keyword. A general type in Haskell is a union of product types, each of which is tagged with a constructor. For example, an `Employee` might be a line worker (with a name and a salary) or a manager (with a name, salary and a list of reports).

We use the `String` type to represent an employee's name, and the `Int` type to represent a salaray. A list of reports is just a list of `Employee`s.

```
data Employee = Worker  String Int
              | Manager String Int [Employee]
```

### Type

The `type` keyword is used to create type synonyms, i.e. alternate names for the same type. This is typically used to make the source more immediately understandable. For example, we could declare a type `Name` for employee names (which is really just a `String`) and `Salary` for salaries (which are just `Int`s), and `Reports` for a list of reports.

```
type Name    = String
type Salary  = Int
type Reports = [Employee]

data Employee = Worker  Name Salary
              | Manager Name Salary Reports
```

### Newtype

The `newtype` keyword is similar to the `type` keyword, but it adds an extra dash of type safety. One problem with the previous block of code is that, although  a worker is a combination of a `Name` and a `Salary`, there is nothing to stop you using any old `String` in the `Name` field (for example, an address). The compiler doesn't distinguish between `Name`s and plain old `String`s, which introduces a class of potential bugs.

With the `newtype` keyword we can make the compiler enforce that the only `String`s that can be used in a `Name` field are the ones explicitly tagged as `Name`s

```
newtype Name    = Name String
newtype Salary  = Salary Int
newtype Reports = Reports [Employee]

data Employee = Worker  Name Salary
              | Manager Name Salary Reports
```

Now if we tried to enter a `String` in the `Name` field without explicitly tagging it, we get a type error

```
>>> let kate = Worker (Name "Kate") (Salary 50000)     -- this is ok
>>> let fred = Worker "18 Tennyson Av." (Salary 40000) -- this will fail

<interactive>:10:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `Name' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `Worker', namely `"18 Tennyson Av."'
    In the expression: Worker "18 Tennyson Av." (Salary 40000)
    In an equation for `fred':
        fred = Worker "18 Tennyson Av." (Salary 40000)
```

What's great about this is that because the compiler knows that a `Name` is really just a `String`, it optimizes away the extra constructor, so this is just as efficient as using a `type` declaration -- the extra type safety comes "for free". This requires an important restriction -- **a `newtype` has exactly one constructor with exactly one value**. Otherwise the compiler wouldn't know which constructor or value was the correct synonym!

One disadvantage of using a `newtype` declaration is that now a `Salary` is no longer just an `Int`, you can't directly add them together. For example

```
>>> let kate'sSalary = Salary 50000
>>> let fred'sSalary = Salary 40000
>>> kate'sSalary + fred'sSalary

<interactive>:14:14:
    No instance for (Num Salary)
      arising from a use of `+'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Salary)
    In the expression: kate'sSalary + fred'sSalary
    In an equation for `it': it = kate'sSalary + fred'sSalary
```

The somewhat complicated error message is telling you that a `Salary` isn't a numeric type, so you can't add them together (or at least, you haven't told the compiler how to add them together). One option would be to define a function that gets the underlying `Int` from the `Salary`

```
getSalary :: Salary -> Int
getSalary (Salary sal) = sal
```

but in fact Haskell will write these for you if you use record syntax when declaring your `newtype`s

```
data Salary = Salary { getSalary :: Int }
```

Now you can write

```
>>> getSalary kate'sSalary + getSalary fred'sSalary
90000
```